# How can I have two different set of routing for same angular app?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app. I would like to deploy it on two different domain names.
My Angular app has two components

- WriterComponent
- ReaderComponent

I want

`writer.mydomain.com to have / mapped to WriterComponent`

`reader.mydomain.com to have / mapped to ReaderComponent`

So I basically deploy same app to two different servers possibly with some different command line arguments to achieve this.

Comment: What are the functional differences between the 2 domains? I assume that there is a lot of shared functionality, hence the desire to deploy one app to 2 locations. You might get some helpful answers if you share your reasons why you want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function inside main app component which will read domain and figure out the value from domain name (use window.location.href), and based on that use *ngIf to show different components.